# In AngularJS ui-router, state changed, url changed but template url not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i tried to follow [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) but using Node.JS

the problem is when i click login button, it's authorized from the server side, the url is changed to http://localhost:3000/#/venue but the view is still the same, and when i check the state in the console, it's already change to venue state too.

Here's my app.js code

```
  var myApp = angular.module('authApp', ['ui.router', 'satellizer']);

    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {
      console.log("Hello World from module");
      $authProvider.loginUrl = '/api/authenticate';

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');      
      $stateProvider

        .state('auth', {
          url: '/auth',
          templateUrl: '/index.html',
          controller:  'AuthController'
        })
        .state('venue', {
          url: '/venue',
          templateUrl: 'venue.html',
          controller: 'VenueController'
        });
    })

  myApp.controller('AuthController',function($scope, $auth, $state) {
    console.log("Hello World from auth controller");
    console.log("current state1: ",$state);

     $scope.login = function() {

      var credentials = {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
      }

      $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
        $state.go('venue',{});
        console.log("current state2: ",$state);

      }, function(error) {   
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  });

  myApp.controller('VenueController', function($scope, $auth, $state) {
    console.log("Hello World from venue controller");
    $scope.getVenues = function() {

      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/venue/1').success(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");          
        $scope.users = response;

      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log('error');
      });
    }

  });
```

and this is my login page (index.html)

```
  <body ng-app="authApp" >

<div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div>Field Booking</div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="login" ng-controller="AuthController" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password"><br>
            <button ng-click="login()" > Login </button>
    </div>
```

i already included angular and ui router source into the header and also try adding ui-view into venue.html but it doesn't load somehow.

Please help, I'm new at AngularJS and it's need to be done soon

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have a `stateParams` to pass, you don't need the second parameter in `$state.go`. Use below instead:

```
$state.go('venue');
```

Also, the issue is that you are not having any `ui-view` directive within which your state will load. Add a `ui-view` directive in your html like this and it will work

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Read more about `ui-view` here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#where-does-the-template-get-inserted